# Points for answer migrated with question, points for edit not migrated

Tags: discussion, reputation, migration, suggested-edits

[This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/34208/10454) was originally posted to [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/).

I posted [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/34209/10454) and submitted a suggested edit, which was approved.

The question was then migrated to [Unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

The order of events was:

1. Question posted to Serverfault
2. I submitted the suggested edit.
3. I posted an answer
4. The suggested edit was approved
5. The question was migrated from Serverfault to Unix
6. My answer was upvoted twice.

My 20 rep points for the upvotes appear on the Unix site.  As I understand it, even if the upvotes had occurred while the question and answer were still on Serverfault, the points would have been migrated (I would have lost 20 points on Serverfault and gained 20 points on Unix).

I got 2 points for the suggested edit.  Those points are still part of my reputation on Serverfault.

Is this the intent?  Why are points from upvotes migrated when the corresponding post is migrated, but points from suggested edits are not?

Also, the migration appears to have lost the edit history.  Is that the intent?  (Should this be a separate question?)

I'm fine either way, I'm just trying to figure out a possibly obscure corner of the rules.